# How do I create a table with a column that uses a sequence?

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I have the following

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [ID] [bigint] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL
)

CREATE SEQUENCE MyTableID
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO CACHE
    ;
GO
```

I want to insert new records on MyTable and set the ID to the next value of the sequence. How can I do it? A trigger perhaps, or is there some other way? How?

As I am using SQL Server 2012, [I don't want to use Identity because of the gap bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assign it as the default property for the column

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [ID] [bigint] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MyTableID),
    [Title] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL
);
```

Future readers, a Sequence *can* have a gap if the service stops unexpectedly, the value of the entities in CACHE can be lost. Here, they are specifying `no cache` to mitigate that with the tradeoff of slower performance for the sequence object.

[CREATE SEQUENCE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) reference

Comment: Is it safe to use `cache` in this case? At the connect link Microsoft tells us to use `no cache`.

Comment: @BrunoLM It depends on how big/small of a db we're talking about and how many transactions per second/minute we're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

To use a `SEQUENCE` in an `INSERT` statement, you could try this:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([ID],[TITLE]) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MyTableID, @TITLE)
```

`NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MyTableID` is the syntax for obtaining the next number from a `SEQUENCE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one sequence for multiple tables, as demonstrated by the following example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.MyTableID
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO CACHE
    ;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[MyTable1]
(
    [ID] [bigint] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MyTableID),
    [Title1] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.[MyTable2]
(
    [ID] [bigint] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MyTableID),
    [Title2] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL
);
```

```
--Insert 2 rows
insert into  [MyTable1] (title1)
select 'title11'

insert into  [MyTable1] (title1)
select 'title12';

insert into  [MyTable2] (title2)
select 'title21'

insert into  [MyTable2] (title2)
select 'title22';

select f1.*, 'Into MyTable1' Tb from  [MyTable1] f1
union all
select f1.*, 'Into MyTable2' Tb from  [MyTable2] f1
```

Output:

```
+----+---------+---------------+
| ID | Title1  |      Tb       |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 | title11 | Into MyTable1 |
|  2 | title12 | Into MyTable1 |
|  3 | title21 | Into MyTable2 |
|  4 | title22 | Into MyTable2 |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bc01f/1)

Comment: This a terrible and very lazy way to do things! Don't do it!

Comment: To say that or to say nothing is the same thing ...